# Bootstrap Date Time Picker Enable Disable Hours

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datetimepicker

How to disable the Specific hours in boostrap date time picker.

My coding as follows:

```
<input type="text" name="start" id="startDateTime" value=""  />
Script As follows :
    if ($('#startDateTime').length)
{
    $('#startDateTime').datetimepicker({
        format: "mm/dd/yyyy HH:ii P",
        showMeridian: true,
        autoclose: true,
        todayBtn: true,
        startDate : new Date()
    });
}
```

[image]

My requirement is need to pick the time only 9 AM to 11PM, rest of the hours need to disable or hide whatever it is.

Comment: can you please mention which bootstrap date/time picker is used because every picker has their own configuration options.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell by reading the documentation (https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/) you can achieve this by using options like `enabledHours`, `disabledHours` or `disabledTimeIntervals`

Comment: The docs have no examples for each function or option
, so it's guesswork.  That said, lots of examples out there - but maybe for different variations, because there is no "standard" for the inputs - each author makes up his own.